Customize the highlight color of a NSTableRowView
I’d like to

Set the emphasized background red.
Preserve the behavior of replacing the emphasized background with unemphasizedSelectedContentBackgroundColor when the content is not key (e.g. we select another element of the UI) or the application is on the background.



macOS uses a rounded rectangle filled with NSColor.selectedContentBackgroundColor to indicate selection. I’ll imitate that but using a custom red color.
The variable isEmphasized becomes false when the control is not key or the application is on the background, so I’ll use it to trigger a refresh and alternate to the unemphasized color.
import AppKit

final class CustomTableRowView: NSTableRowView {
    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        // the default .none doesn’t call drawSelection(in:)
        selectionHighlightStyle = .regular
    }

    override func drawSelection(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        guard selectionHighlightStyle != .none else { 
            return 
        }
        let selectionRect = NSInsetRect(bounds, 10, 0)
        let fillColor = isEmphasized ? NSColor.red : NSColor.unemphasizedSelectedContentBackgroundColor
        fillColor.setFill()
        let selectionPath = NSBezierPath.init(roundedRect: selectionRect, xRadius: 5, yRadius: 5)
        selectionPath.fill()
    }

    override var isEmphasized: Bool {
        didSet {
            needsDisplay = true
        }
    }
}

Finally, I tell the NSViewController to use the custom class above:
// MARK: - NSOutlineViewDelegate

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, rowViewForItem item: Any) -> NSTableRowView? {
    CustomTableRowView()
}

